# Cannot use wildcard subdomains with Convox Gen3?

Tags: convox

We run a cloud platform with subdomains for each customer (similar to how Shopify has mystore.myshopify.com).

It currently runs as a Gen1 app, and will likely need to be upgraded soon.
According to the docs however, it's not possible to use wildcard subdomains due to an issue with Let's Encrypt?

https://docs.convox.com/deployment/custom-domains

**Does this make Convox a non-option for us moving forward?**

We also offer customers the ability to use a custom domain (also similar to Shopify) but would this mean we would need to configure each domain with Convox on the convox.yml level, and have the customer sent a Let's Encrypt validation email?

Answer (score -1):

LetsEncrypt doesn’t use validation emails. As long as the DNS resolves to the Rack router, LetsEncrypt will issue the cert.

So while you would have to specify each sub-domain in their convox.yml, the email thing isn’t an issue. You can specify the domains through the use of an env var which they can update rather than actually changing the file each time.

You could also use Gen2 which has ongoing support and development. Gen2 and Gen3 are just different pathways to achieve relatively the same thing. https://docsv2.convox.com/gen1/ssl